# R: How do I convert gene symbols to Entrez IDs?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I want to convert the **gene symbols** in `gene.list` to **Entrez IDs** using the `mapIDs` function.

Edit:
I also want to remove the genes that don't map to an Entrez ID.

```
library(org.Hs.eg.db)
library(AnnotationDbi)

# Read in the gene list from Supplementary Table 1
gene.list <- read.table("Table_1_Differential Expression Analysis Revealing CLCA1 to Be a Prognostic and Diagnostic Biomarker for Colorectal Cancer.xls", header=T)
gene.list <- as.data.frame(gene.list)
gene.list <- mapIds(org.Hs.eg.db, keys=gene.list[,1], column="SYMBOL", keytype="ENTREZID")
```

Traceback:

```
Error in .testForValidKeys(x, keys, keytype, fks) : 
  None of the keys entered are valid keys for 'ENTREZID'. Please use the keys method to see a listing of valid arguments.
```

Data

```
> dput(gene.list)
structure(list(Name = c("AQP8", "CLCA1", "GUCA2B", "ZG16", "CA4", 
"CA1", "GUCA2A", "MS4A12", "FCGBP", "CLDN8", "GCG", "AKR1B10", 
"CWH43", "SLC26A3", "SELENBP1", "PYY", "ADH1C", "SCNN1B", "BEST2", 
"ABCG2", "CEACAM7", "HEPACAM2", "SI", "ADAMDEC1", "SLC26A2", 
"HSD11B2", "CA2", "NR3C2", "SCGB2A1", "ITLN1", "TNFRSF17", "MT1M", 
"CHP2", "PKIB", "CA7", "DNASE1L3", "CLCA4", "STMN2", "ADH1B", 
"TSPAN7", "CHGA", "LGALS2", "HSD17B2", "MUC4", "SLC4A4", "BCAS1", 
"NXPE4", "BEST4", "ANPEP", "CD177", "HPGD", "SPINK2", "VSIG2", 
"SLC9A2", "LRRC19", "NAT2", "PDE9A", "PCK1", "PTGDR", "EDN3", 
"MUC2", "SLC17A4", "SST", "C2orf88", "ADTRP", "EPHX2", "GPA33", 
"MAOA", "SULT1B1", "TRPM6", "MEP1A", "BTNL8", "HMGCS2", "UGT2B17", 
"UGT2A3", "PLCE1", "ACADS", "PDE6A", "ENTPD5", "DHRS9", "RGS13", 
"MT1F", "KRT20", "C10orf99", "ARL14", "ABCA8", "LAMA1", "SPINK5", 
"AMPD1", "GBA3", "CNTN3", "AGR3", "KLRB1", "CCL28", "FAM150B", 
"CFD", "PLP1", "MB", "FABP1", "SLC51B", "LDHD", "PNLIPRP2", "AHCYL2", 
"C1orf115", "NR1H4", "CKB", "SLC28A2", "PRKACB", "CLDN23", "CA12", 
"RUNDC3B", "MYO1A", "CPM", "SLC16A9", "CDKN2B", "BMP2", "TUBAL3", 
"SMPDL3A", "MT1G", "HSD3B2", "TMEM100", "PTPRH", "SCGN", "MALL", 
"SLITRK6", "RETNLB", "MAMDC2", "BCHE", "FMO5", "INSL5", "MEP1B", 
"C11orf86", "DEFB1", "SCIN", "PAPSS2", "CES2", "GHR", "PLCD1", 
"ISX", "EPB41L3", "C7", "CCDC68", "LYPD8", "ITM2A", "GCNT3", 
"PADI2", "TSPAN1", "MMP28", "NXPE1", "CD36", "PLAC8", "TMEM171", 
"MT1H", "SLC25A34", "IL1R2", "HHLA2", "DHRS11", "IGJ", "XDH", 
"FUCA1", "ANK3", "SEMA6A", "PIGR", "FABP2", "NR5A2", "GCNT2", 
"UGT2B15", "PIGZ", "TEX11", "BTNL3", "FABP4", "IQGAP2", "MT1E", 
"SCN9A", "CLIC5", "MYOT", "BMP3", "GDPD2", "SOSTDC1", "OGN", 
"TMEM37", "TLR3", "ABHD3", "CAPN13", "METTL7A", "ZBTB7C", "SCUBE2", 
"PLCL2", "NPY1R", "NKX2-3", "ITM2C", "C2orf40", "NAP1L2", "IGHM", 
"SPIB", "TMIGD1", "KLF4", "CDHR5", "TMCC3", "PDK4", "GREM2", 
"ABI3BP", "PTPRR", "SCARA5", "CDKN2B-AS1", "TRHDE", "PBLD", "SLC30A10", 
"SLC51A", "RHBDL2", "VSTM2A", "BRINP3"), Pvalue = c(3.24077275512836e-22, 
2.57708986670727e-21, 5.53491656902485e-21, 4.14482213350182e-20, 
2.7795892896524e-19, 1.23890644641685e-18, 2.08086109472981e-18, 
3.71686071848627e-18, 5.02015157731556e-18, 5.29675993728991e-18, 
9.91526703938225e-18, 3.04600157720094e-17, 3.82334758986503e-17, 
7.79800719906674e-17, 7.9165351686704e-16, 1.26464750028061e-15, 
1.33390513381201e-15, 1.6959409570969e-15, 1.8610521316308e-15, 
4.91533416963819e-15, 5.33415387607992e-15, 5.33415387607992e-15, 
7.16706210095408e-15, 7.91854095362355e-15, 8.54724230611173e-15, 
8.67986104627575e-15, 9.21823269094804e-15, 1.25629228944705e-14, 
2.62162260687696e-14, 3.05313510901903e-14, 3.17491475337798e-14, 
3.30811992851482e-14, 5.0515106987893e-14, 5.0515106987893e-14, 
5.68405659634921e-14, 5.68405659634921e-14, 6.59381778132483e-14, 
7.28151955670785e-14, 9.07408638621435e-14, 9.07408638621435e-14, 
1.01038177126755e-13, 1.12320598527624e-13, 1.24665357114941e-13, 
2.4108521806048e-13, 2.60246059029555e-13, 2.93575706481917e-13, 
3.57876275843414e-13, 4.77124886637553e-13, 5.98564106154148e-13, 
6.86080407902475e-13, 7.63667305169733e-13, 8.18541981145862e-13, 
1.00421640487562e-12, 1.03201869423082e-12, 1.04947067067708e-12, 
1.16781268980735e-12, 1.29265274909297e-12, 1.40077143241398e-12, 
1.84399992003164e-12, 2.22722040199405e-12, 3.5393726685631e-12, 
3.65422479503361e-12, 4.13197190599787e-12, 4.19434157123909e-12, 
5.08282668084517e-12, 5.43540309240712e-12, 5.91036288681546e-12, 
6.00958865636123e-12, 6.74587705173367e-12, 6.90995200196637e-12, 
7.54857158199781e-12, 7.77965957232345e-12, 8.22305800512328e-12, 
1.03603285311011e-11, 1.05649881033747e-11, 1.14628439394548e-11, 
1.17378194824993e-11, 1.1776286057306e-11, 1.22869698760514e-11, 
2.50391193814412e-11, 2.7172063046623e-11, 3.05854823676429e-11, 
3.20501090228437e-11, 3.51602199011144e-11, 3.56391592903737e-11, 
4.06580502619134e-11, 4.71176982940451e-11, 5.25779592935779e-11, 
5.40034087903282e-11, 6.38385880881368e-11, 6.50882225009279e-11, 
6.64704308289937e-11, 7.89688183060643e-11, 9.2257919626623e-11, 
1.02702091032914e-10, 1.28792299680013e-10, 1.45686932827503e-10, 
1.63839704116511e-10, 1.73361282103191e-10, 1.97182642592672e-10, 
2.03309742743294e-10, 3.52187301295396e-10, 3.7088140591403e-10, 
3.73751066915676e-10, 3.98716208664828e-10, 4.29080153096584e-10, 
5.19119508796453e-10, 5.24053028675558e-10, 5.51581201793396e-10, 
7.51368795294162e-10, 8.35967738234462e-10, 9.55964846612075e-10, 
9.6969056401234e-10, 1.05563639887841e-09, 1.11434040768162e-09, 
1.11648257460303e-09, 1.14801348452055e-09, 1.21625259377534e-09, 
1.23297016072789e-09, 1.26421298715716e-09, 1.36191837776683e-09, 
1.63264567715795e-09, 1.63264567715795e-09, 1.69842715162968e-09, 
1.85423796318681e-09, 1.90496350300461e-09, 2.13796120098069e-09, 
2.14269885897935e-09, 2.54232306938895e-09, 2.67542142351259e-09, 
2.72798521011557e-09, 2.73483945851302e-09, 2.85697013492621e-09, 
3.39181801861512e-09, 3.5807267509976e-09, 3.88663170713946e-09, 
4.07125729913743e-09, 4.46308577167802e-09, 4.51425686923126e-09, 
4.52767375818418e-09, 4.56592847034147e-09, 5.05417282432332e-09, 
5.08918205367341e-09, 5.10291066931136e-09, 5.16787115297972e-09, 
5.51915336842277e-09, 5.71090027571611e-09, 5.71090027571611e-09, 
5.76105182052558e-09, 6.09888668424418e-09, 6.31543328139757e-09, 
6.43660556302915e-09, 6.55970351161761e-09, 6.77516723879691e-09, 
7.03672005186854e-09, 8.13635509066867e-09, 8.19614852099653e-09, 
8.52845406888475e-09, 8.9333567206728e-09, 9.13152964150643e-09, 
9.79611773441657e-09, 9.80666158228691e-09, 1.04100049518692e-08, 
1.0772582173387e-08, 1.11674622388334e-08, 1.12794193446903e-08, 
1.20082852097958e-08, 1.41327530031073e-08, 1.60302706870783e-08, 
1.6558646084973e-08, 1.87634392446641e-08, 1.90572800184574e-08, 
1.98303161562218e-08, 2.00130693087331e-08, 2.00130693087331e-08, 
2.10018274055026e-08, 2.22143693913833e-08, 2.33907594776291e-08, 
2.34578880926338e-08, 2.46321702907257e-08, 2.56140478525681e-08, 
2.98086294831038e-08, 3.22762272168626e-08, 3.48424608495869e-08, 
3.68589011518126e-08, 3.86966148158414e-08, 4.92219046896786e-08, 
5.11283238324901e-08, 5.3347501034798e-08, 5.47561618795827e-08, 
5.62175333112453e-08, 5.93945625594121e-08, 6.00131603429523e-08, 
7.17888890565631e-08, 8.99615590588753e-08, 9.20237217855503e-08, 
9.30563899089323e-08, 9.64185741429093e-08, 1.0333272757575e-07, 
1.29148016306951e-07, 1.49510028520842e-07, 1.81374404459134e-07, 
1.85988924853564e-07, 1.90193193020603e-07, 2.20591626756214e-07, 
2.36768484405735e-07, 2.7022082242764e-07, 2.82905208452177e-07, 
4.73453502573963e-07, 8.71356435715292e-07, 1.1851366713074e-06, 
1.35540367180997e-06), adjPvalue = c(8.3845272720681e-18, 6.66744690314504e-17, 
1.43199361473811e-16, 1.07234838237959e-15, 7.19135341018869e-15, 
3.20529875816967e-14, 5.38360382428497e-14, 9.61626205086768e-14, 
1.29881361608308e-13, 1.37037773097565e-13, 2.56527788842898e-13, 
7.88061528053426e-13, 9.8917648844988e-13, 2.01750042254255e-12, 
2.04816597883841e-11, 3.27189601272599e-11, 3.45107936219843e-11, 
4.38773844420109e-11, 4.8149140749552e-11, 1.27169525636879e-10, 
1.3800522908194e-10, 1.3800522908194e-10, 1.85426230675884e-10, 
2.04868491552149e-10, 2.21134252943723e-10, 2.24565364989246e-10, 
2.38494116180208e-10, 3.25027941125742e-10, 6.78266200851208e-10, 
7.89907115405404e-10, 8.21413944993951e-10, 8.55876787905354e-10, 
1.30692684799077e-09, 1.30692684799077e-09, 1.47057912260747e-09, 
1.47057912260747e-09, 1.70595253638436e-09, 1.88387473971145e-09, 
2.34764762984138e-09, 2.34764762984138e-09, 2.61405971862342e-09, 
2.90595852510669e-09, 3.22534211927776e-09, 6.23735676166074e-09, 
6.73308603921264e-09, 7.59539067810015e-09, 9.25897500862082e-09, 
1.23441750670868e-08, 1.54860505544201e-08, 1.77502723132528e-08, 
1.97576005193513e-08, 2.11773181362058e-08, 2.59810868269421e-08, 
2.67003876571397e-08, 2.71519051917574e-08, 3.02136499106959e-08, 
3.34435119245334e-08, 3.62407584994146e-08, 4.77079659310586e-08, 
5.76226462403902e-08, 9.15706496810646e-08, 9.45421038971095e-08, 
1.06902377151977e-07, 1.08516005131098e-07, 1.31502891886826e-07, 
1.40624748806757e-07, 1.5291290860769e-07, 1.55480077717378e-07, 
1.74529331082453e-07, 1.78774278194874e-07, 1.95296643969447e-07, 
2.01275352455152e-07, 2.12746956708549e-07, 2.68042419756647e-07, 
2.73337372210511e-07, 2.96566698401574e-07, 3.03680865651222e-07, 
3.0467607287462e-07, 3.17888484633201e-07, 6.47812096636647e-07, 
7.0299561514223e-07, 7.91307599815656e-07, 8.29200420639013e-07, 
9.09665209281631e-07, 9.22056329160548e-07, 1.05190507637622e-06, 
1.21902909026353e-06, 1.36029696284345e-06, 1.39717619222337e-06, 
1.65163195101627e-06, 1.68396249254401e-06, 1.71972298640773e-06, 
2.0430812672145e-06, 2.38689689657999e-06, 2.65710849920354e-06, 
3.33211437732129e-06, 3.76921232611317e-06, 4.23886082490238e-06, 
4.48520309057376e-06, 5.10150932915762e-06, 5.2600296642545e-06, 
9.11178985911449e-06, 9.59544373380777e-06, 9.66968760324238e-06, 
1.03155857505764e-05, 1.11011617209148e-05, 1.34306599315818e-05, 
1.3558299957894e-05, 1.42705088527987e-05, 1.94394134718506e-05, 
2.1628157323602e-05, 2.47327225115476e-05, 2.50878342721273e-05, 
2.73114249117823e-05, 2.88302150275388e-05, 2.88856371701296e-05, 
2.97014048715156e-05, 3.14668871061556e-05, 3.18994039983521e-05, 
3.27077184037301e-05, 3.52355522695834e-05, 4.22398089594304e-05, 
4.22398089594304e-05, 4.3941707266963e-05, 4.79728445835691e-05, 
4.92852157497352e-05, 5.53133321917725e-05, 5.54359048795138e-05, 
6.57749824512308e-05, 6.92185030691177e-05, 7.05784333561101e-05, 
7.07557664706488e-05, 7.3915531330811e-05, 8.77531157776104e-05, 
9.26405625018099e-05, 0.000100554935527112, 0.000105331568843284, 
0.000115468955084854, 0.000116792853720751, 0.000117139975471741, 
0.000118129701384675, 0.000130761559310893, 0.000131667318092639, 
0.000132022504836423, 0.000133703162469891, 0.000142791535947834, 
0.000147752411933327, 0.000147752411933327, 0.000149049932700638, 
0.000157790396294765, 0.000163392889856318, 0.00016652785912669, 
0.000169712649252571, 0.000175287126802154, 0.000182054021181943, 
0.00021050377890578, 0.000212050754535222, 0.000220648163670186, 
0.000231123805077247, 0.000236250934885054, 0.000253445158024826, 
0.000253717948456927, 0.00026932764811476, 0.000278708245989868, 
0.000288924583043097, 0.000291821137285827, 0.000310678354947837, 
0.000365642585696393, 0.00041473516321609, 0.000428405291510422, 
0.00048544770013795, 0.00049304994863753, 0.00051304993959377, 
0.000517778129155543, 0.000517778129155543, 0.000543359278635163, 
0.000574730164893868, 0.000605165729205219, 0.00060690248073262, 
0.000637283509761654, 0.000662686646041642, 0.000771208861986861, 
0.00083505055055467, 0.000901444147100513, 0.000953613490599696, 
0.00100115881851545, 0.00127346911813136, 0.00132279199419418, 
0.00138020654677229, 0.00141665142014856, 0.00145446002182854, 
0.00153665612253711, 0.00155266048439286, 0.0018573221376714, 
0.00232748545597122, 0.00238083773003576, 0.0024075549197239, 
0.00249454135022535, 0.00267342432783981, 0.00334131747789343, 
0.00386812345789123, 0.00469251859216671, 0.00481190546381141, 
0.00492067828982905, 0.00570714656743676, 0.00612567422854519, 
0.00699115311784791, 0.00731932355307473, 0.0122491890185936, 
0.022543733704826, 0.0306618559600649, 0.0350670037970675), logFC = c(-3.73323340223377, 
-2.96422555675244, -3.34493724166712, -2.87787132076412, -2.87670608798164, 
-3.15664667432159, -2.95572379364751, -3.11776226961584, -2.35537732355133, 
-2.67721871552053, -2.75129610760123, -2.27084414996904, -2.39032889111821, 
-2.384338011394, -1.52763374598804, -2.00860860118635, -2.47346124923414, 
-1.77694418475864, -1.89128440217407, -2.19479752561645, -2.18821599445392, 
-2.10427393868417, -1.95485254743401, -1.68051092002172, -2.23288175058069, 
-1.55599182329306, -2.52323363507637, -1.61677940479039, -1.85266906568542, 
-1.96077064837331, -1.96370011101605, -2.17842791093474, -2.24624889090768, 
-1.9433059286399, -1.72194537032388, -1.59258674064274, -2.73944416493697, 
-1.72991680856905, -1.91978678918384, -1.53745046096681, -2.58265712006171, 
-1.89096468707109, -2.07646463308581, -1.31273716151829, -2.03249775411443, 
-1.36181201643591, -2.06899407025227, -1.87048715347246, -1.91667530474797, 
-2.1461616618427, -1.6479787691362, -1.33378640988632, -1.72215015147883, 
-1.34052441351924, -1.7043113995856, -1.33793772688176, -1.71905799963657, 
-1.57695717580076, -1.41323337312048, -1.59338624392593, -1.64643122321121, 
-1.75988448337732, -1.98951543307092, -1.82348813980001, -1.37404089130313, 
-1.21392252107995, -1.23444210208399, -1.0504026194805, -1.36995028694564, 
-1.68148390549027, -1.52623916337882, -1.55196435704358, -1.62044142475669, 
-1.90123852748856, -1.62740353308111, -1.33286613920314, -1.20736572248892, 
-1.26754967738884, -1.38081367775472, -1.74503838424159, -1.31993161308477, 
-1.25614441032473, -1.16604666773954, -1.39374057364964, -1.15564016736398, 
-1.59538567063783, -1.72516032332254, -1.20031738020499, -1.54934514193547, 
-1.69813954071306, -1.49173202517221, -1.13037379139493, -1.06992187351818, 
-1.11872471223904, -1.50025731755795, -1.4786956336749, -1.70169613382508, 
-1.11543778045488, -1.25246156765558, -1.41219265401308, -1.34216716634308, 
-1.21483888538237, -1.18783194980572, -1.27995050394471, -1.54673371527308, 
-1.1772177296832, -1.27197622794611, -1.15735584206148, -1.3145443012282, 
-1.40637007862426, -1.28428168377161, -1.15447080939736, -1.0771004700913, 
-1.06144307224307, -1.32201187239143, -1.02334819830918, -1.2717095451404, 
-1.42662160815622, -1.30886936099932, -1.31688198651383, -1.17091310361446, 
-1.01260162483386, -1.02950842641754, -1.03643855051167, -1.37556505576263, 
-1.23862205517648, -1.3740360097265, -1.00214833417688, -1.10684627082633, 
-1.32151991472107, -1.50146103453149, -1.3247286578691, -1.11593725282829, 
-1.33992760573976, -1.03151712296378, -1.07391001123839, -1.03336450028305, 
-1.09415551430876, -1.34757655182154, -1.17369200392523, -1.00232684401995, 
-1.0086972885472, -1.65090199334683, -1.0492155481647, -1.22927607516148, 
-1.27262833853532, -1.25940761060468, -1.00675842034134, -1.32657811831383, 
-1.02309643568646, -1.31967986144086, -1.33361345645053, -1.46153658305282, 
-1.00162150576799, -1.30997779462544, -1.38743518056205, -1.15750932405615, 
-1.03930938307668, -1.1017274935713, -1.0849003122503, -1.00002524430596, 
-1.11484305623185, -1.23766205424291, -1.35400463988853, -1.02990325461034, 
-1.1878375784046, -1.47409982601536, -1.06800405196352, -1.29328068120638, 
-1.27809212263698, -1.28053420817819, -1.04686740740476, -1.01454529904826, 
-1.02580331884153, -1.02136228096711, -1.33225577482151, -1.32192907964515, 
-1.26070218311376, -1.24410892618385, -1.24329526989428, -1.18923754607858, 
-1.06581647047304, -1.06278085909063, -1.07456550801011, -1.11235974156269, 
-1.08497061358243, -1.24141902733644, -1.20548081629222, -1.04742395413826, 
-1.03350625537176, -1.03364856848473, -1.39339556649799, -1.02383679771273, 
-1.05203938193841, -1.11127405419432, -1.71455102801661, -1.10924995375228, 
-1.08640481444917, -1.08616822461293, -1.09970612861119, -1.25626485503098, 
-1.24377500579313, -1.06656097156214, -1.20013695037315, -1.02320980302181, 
-1.08297463543096, -1.18767984312194, -1.49240766255859, -1.31261354843641, 
-1.04146525952501, -1.13237121184317, -1.13021396190798)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-212L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the arguments mixed up. Your `keytype` is `SYMBOL` and what you need is `ncbi-geneid`s (aka `ENTREZID` (old name))

```
mapIds(org.Hs.eg.db, keys = genelist$Name,
       column = "ENTREZID", keytype = "SYMBOL")
```

Output (truncated)

```
'select()' returned 1:1 mapping between keys and
columns
       AQP8       CLCA1      GUCA2B        ZG16         CA4 
      "343"      "1179"      "2981"    "653808"       "762" 
        CA1      GUCA2A      MS4A12       FCGBP       CLDN8 
      "759"      "2980"     "54860"      "8857"      "9073" 
        GCG     AKR1B10       CWH43     SLC26A3    SELENBP1 
     "2641"     "57016"     "80157"      "1811"      "8991"
```

EDIT

If you would like to drop non mapped results, then

```
genelist %>% 
mutate(entrez = mapIds(org.Hs.eg.db, keys = genelist$Name,
       column = "ENTREZID", keytype = "SYMBOL")) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(entrez))
```

Comment: Traceback:
`'select()' returned 1:1 mapping between keys and columns`

Comment: It is a message not an error (unless of course it returns no output)

Comment: Edit:
I also want to remove the genes that don't map to an Entrez ID.

Comment: if it does not map, it will be `NA`, simply run `na.omit(mapped_genes)` or you can remove them in the original df by checking if the mapped result is an NA (this may be fun to explore)

Comment: you mean `na.omit(gene.list)`?

Comment: No, `na.omit` on the result of the map. An alternative is to check which genes in `Name` are `NA` in the map and remove them. OK, I will add an edit on how to do this. @melolili, added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242046/discussion-between-melolili-and-nelsongon).